# A que campo tengo que llamar para comprobar la firma digital de mi documento XML usando C#

Tags: c#, firma-digital, rsa

Para comprobar la firma estoy usando el ejemplo de Microsoft que tienen es este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-verify-the-digital-signatures-of-xml-documents)

Aclaro igual que ya tengo firmado el documento usando una llave rsa y n509 y utilizo el método *envelope*, este es el código de cómo firmo (en caso de ser necesario):

```html
#region Firma RSA & N509
        private void btn_Firmax509_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ubicación de mi certificado esto puede variar o se podría generar un botón en donde la gente vaya a buscar el certificado
            string Certificate = "C:/LocalMachine/my/tstCert.cer";

            try
            {
                // Generate a signing key.
                RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                SignXmlFile(path, path3, Key, Certificate);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
            }

        }

        public static void SignXmlFile(string FileName, string SignedFileName, RSA Key, string Certificate)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = true; 
            doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName)); 
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc); 
            signedXml.SigningKey = Key;   
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)Key));

            X509Certificate MSCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(MSCert));


            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignatureRSA = signedXml.GetXml(); 

            // Agrego al documento un hijo, primero la rsa y después la x509
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignatureRSA, true));
                       
            if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
            {
                doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
            }

            //guardo el documento
            XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(SignedFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
            doc.WriteTo(xmltw);
            xmltw.Close();
        }
        #endregion
```

Y este es el botón y la función para verificar si se firmó bien el documento:

```html
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";

                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

                // Create a new XML document.
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                xmlDoc.Load(path3);


                MessageBox.Show("Verificando Firma");
                bool result = VerifyXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

                // Display the results of the signature verification to 
                // the console.
                if (result)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La firma XML es valida");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La firma XML no es valida");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
            }



        }

        public static Boolean VerifyXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA key)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (xmlDoc == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("key");

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
            }

            // This example only supports one signature for
            // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception 
            // if more than one signature was found.
            if (nodeList.Count >= 2)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
            }

            // Load the first <signature> node.  
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

            // Check the signature and return the result.
            return signedXml.CheckSignature(key);
        }
```

Sin modificar los valores que trae el  código de la verificación de la firma me arroja que esta no es valida, me imagino que es porque tengo más de una firma en el **Signature** y no sabe cual buscar. Acá me pierdo un poco en temas de concepto. Mi firma viene a ser: DigestValue, SignatureValue o ya de frentón RSAKeyValue?

porque si es una de esas tres supongo que modificando la linea que dice:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
```

Podría hacer que esta verificación me salga como exitosa con mi programa a menos que tenga que modificar algo más.

Espero alguien me pueda orientar u ayudar con esto.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás buscando el nodo de Signature pero aún no validas el XML.

En [la docuemntación de `XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigenvelopedsignaturetransform?view=netcore-2.2) contiene herramientas para firmas digitales de los XML en base a la W3C.

En la clase de `XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform` tiene una función llamada `VerifyXmlFile(String Name)` el cual valida el xml y escribe el nodo de Signature y entrega como respuesta un booleano. Esto da la versatilidad de validarlo después de crearlo o desde que lo llamas.
Esto lo puedes verificar desde tu botón, o al firmar, o desde se te haga mejor.

```
var esValido = VerifyXmlFile(xml.Name);
```

Código de la documentación

```
public static Boolean VerifyXmlFile(String Name)
{
    // Create a new XML document.
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    // Format using white spaces.
    xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;

    // Load the passed XML file into the document. 
    xmlDocument.Load(Name);

    // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it
    // the XML document class.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);

    // Find the "Signature" node and create a new
    // XmlNodeList object.
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

    // Load the signature node.
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

    // Check the signature and return the result.
    return signedXml.CheckSignature();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo por mi parte voy a buscar dentro de esta documentación para poder validar mediante N509